# How do I change my Profile Icon?

Tags: overwatch

I know that you can equip a new Profile Icon if you have just unlocked it by unboxing a Loot Box, but I cannot figure out how to change your profile icon. I've tried clicking on the profile icon but it brings me to the friends list menu, and nothing in the options menu shows how to change the profile icon image.

How do you change the Profile Icon?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39350/discussion-between-strixvaria-and-o-o).

Comment: Don't know why this is getting so heavily downvoted, it's not immediately obvious in the game how to do this and the icons are the only thing not in the Hero Gallery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change your Profile Icon, you must:

1. Select `Career Profile` on the left hand menu
   [image]
2. Select `Player Icon` on the top bar
   [image]
3. Select the Profile Icon desired
   [image]
4. Select `Equip`